# open scene graph

Tags: visual-studio-2010, openscenegraph

while I was building  the open scene graph 2.8.5 library on visual stdio 2010  the build failed because of these two errors and I can't deal with them   ,

Error   192 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\win\Desktop\another\OpenSceneGraph-2.8.5\open scene graph\bin\osgPlugins-2.8.5\osgdb_rgbd.dll'    C:\Users\win\Desktop\another\OpenSceneGraph-2.8.5\open scene graph\src\osgPlugins\rgb\LINK  Plugins rgb

Error   47  error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\win\Desktop\another\OpenSceneGraph-2.8.5\open scene graph\bin\osgPlugins-2.8.5\osgdb_plyd.dll'    C:\Users\win\Desktop\another\OpenSceneGraph-2.8.5\open scene graph\src\osgPlugins\ply\LINK  Plugins ply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to look back and see WHY those two binaries (osgdb_rgbd.dll and plyd.dll) didn't build.